# R: network plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to make a network plot using 100 nodes I randomly generate from my function.

```
genNodes = function(n){
numKeep <- 0
i = numKeep
x <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 0)
y <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 0)
 while(i < n){
  newx = runif(n = 7*n, min = 0, max = 100)
newy = runif(n = 7*n, min = 0, max = 100)
newz = runif(n = 7*n, min = 0, max = 4)
RangeZ = nodeDensity(newx, newy)
newx = newx[newz <= RangeZ]
newy = newy[newz <= RangeZ]
x = c(x, newx)
y = c(y, newy)
i = length(x)
 }
x <- x[1:n]
y <- y[1:n]
return(cbind(x, y))
}
```

Every node here is in the region (0,100). What I'm trying to do is make a scatterplot of those nodes, (which I know I can use ggplot with geom_point). But I'm also trying to turn that scatter plot into a network plot and still preserve the original scatter plot, which means I want to add edges to the original scatter plot, and I want to preserve the scale of x and y axis. I've tried to use ggnet2 and ggnetwork but they cannot preserve the original scatterplot(Or maybe I just don't know how to correctly use them).

For simplicity(in the case there are only 3nodes in the network), the following information is provided.

•Nodes:
`x = c(1, 2, 3) y = c(5, 5, 2)`
•Transition matrix(Used to determine whether there are edges between two nodes):

`tranR3.5 = matrix(c(1/2, 1/2, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/2, 1/2), 
                  byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)`

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do it in ggplot? If not, try igraph:

```
library(igraph)
test.net1 = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(tranR3.5,
            mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE) 
plot.igraph(test.net1, layout = cbind(x,y), 
            edge.width=E(test.net1)$weight)
```

EDIT: If you want to see the scale, not just preserve it, I'd do:

```
plot(c(0,4), c(0,6), type = "n", frame.plot = F) #set up plot window
plot.igraph(test.net1, layout = cbind(x,y), 
            edge.width=E(test.net1)$weight, add = T, rescale = F)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to do this in ggnet2 or ggnetwork

Comment: and I tried the code you put here, it still does not show the x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: updated code to show axes. not sure off the top of my head how to do it in ggnet2.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using `ggraph`.

You can first make your transition matrix into a edge data frame. (There is probably a better way to do this, but I will use `igraph`). Then you can create a data frame of node information. This is all so you can create a `tidygraph` object to plot with your coordinates.

```
library(igraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

### Prepare data 
x <- c(1, 2, 3) 
y <- c(5, 5, 2)

tranR3.5 <-matrix(c(1/2, 1/2, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/2, 1/2), 
                  byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)

colnames(tranR3.5)<-rownames(tranR3.5)<-c("A","B","C")

g1<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(tranR3.5,mode = "undirected",
                                weighted=TRUE)
edge_df<-get.data.frame(g1,what="edges")

ID<-data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:3],
               x=x,
               y=y)

####Create tidygraph object
g<-tbl_graph(ID,edge_df, directed = FALSE)


#####Plot using ggraph
ggraph(g) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y),colour="red")+
  geom_edge_link(aes(width = weight),alpha=0.2)
```